# Select2 + Rails 4 / Strong Parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, jquery-select2, strong-parameters

**BACKGROUND:** Posts have many Communities. On my new post form, I have a multiple select box for selecting communities using Select2.

When selecting a community without Select2, I get these params, and everything works ok:

```
...{"community_ids"=>["","1"]},...
```

When selecting a community with Select2 I get:

```
...{"community_ids"=>["[],1"]},...
```

which throws a `Couldn't find Community with id=0` error. I've narrowed it down to having something to do with how strong parameters works. I'm guessing Rails is trying to find a community with and id of "[]"? This is in my PostsController:

```
def post_params
  params[:post].permit(:post_field1, :post_field2, { :community_ids => [] })
end
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What rails is doing is taking the input ("[],1") and calling `to_i` on it (to integer). So you get `"[],1".to_i #=> 0`. You would somehow need to split ["[],1"] into ["[]","1"]

Comment: What version of Select2 are you using? Also, can you post your JavaScript code?

Comment: @jokklan you should post that comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What rails is doing is taking the input (`"[],1"`) and calling `to_i` on it (to integer). So you get

`"[],1".to_i #=> 0`

You would somehow need to split `["[],1"]` into `["[]","1"]`.